# Finding the normal form of a finite group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I've got a finite, abelian group and I know the order of all of the elements.

How far does that get me towards knowing what the group is up to isomorphism?

The group has eight elements. Excluding the identity, three elements have order two, while four elements have order four.

I also have the group tables, and I know that I could shuffle the rows and columns looking for some patterns to emerge, but I'd rather have a theoretical approach.

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with the [fundamental theorem of abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Classification)?

Comment: You already know that the group is abelian, but this could be deduced from the symmetry of the (Cayley) table above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tells you everything: take an element $a$ of order 4, look at the subgroup it generates; find a non-identity element $b$ in the complement of this group. If $b$ has order 2, keep it; if not, square it and it'll have order 2. At this point, your group is generated by $a$ and $b$ with $a^4 = b^2 = e$ and $ab = ba$. And that's the complete structure.

In your particular group, $C$ has order $4$, with the subgroup generated by it being 
$$
Id, C, B, D
$$
and so $A$, in the complement of this subgroup, serves as the other generator. Your group is (or is isomorphic to)

$$
\mathbb Z/ 4\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z
$$
with the first factor generated by $C$ and the second by $A$. Let me make that more explicit:

Consider the map
\begin{align}
Id &\mapsto (0,0) \\
C &\mapsto (1,0) \\
B &\mapsto (2,0) \\
D &\mapsto (3,0) \\
A &\mapsto (0,1) \\
AC = E &\mapsto (1, 1)\\
AB = G & \mapsto (2, 1)\\
AD = F &\mapsto (3, 1) 
\end{align}
That's an explicit isomorphism of groups.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/4 \mathbb Z$?

Comment: Fixed, thanks. I did mean that, albeit in the other order. :)

Comment: If pick an element and generate its subgroup, then pick an element not in that subgroup and generate its subgroup. What does it mean/what do I do if this second subgroup contains elements of the first? For example, I have an abelian group with six elements: $\{\mathrm{id},A,B,C,D,E\}$ where $\langle E \rangle = \{E, \mathrm{id}\}$, $\langle A \rangle = \{ A, B, \mathrm{id}\}$, and $\langle C \rangle = \{C, B, E, A, D, \mathrm{id}\}$. I think that $G \cong \mathbb Z/ 3\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups is something of a sledgehammer for this problem, but anyways: any abelian group of order $8$ is isomorphic to one of $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, or $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Your group has no element of order $8$, which rules out the first case, and every element of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ has order $2$, so your group must be $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Is it true that a finitely generated abelian group of order $n$ can be written as

$$\bigoplus_{i=1}^k \mathbb Z/n_i\mathbb Z$$

where $n_1n_2\ldots n_k = n$?

Comment: @FlybyNight: yes, and in fact you can place stronger conditions on the $n_{i}$. This is the content of the fundamental theorem of finitely generated groups, as linked to by Mariano above.

Comment: Yes. In fact, it's even stronger: you can arrange it so that each $n_i$ divides $n_{i+1}$. Check out Wikipedia on the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups.